# Bootstrap button width is wider than normal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, width

I have problem with bootstrap. At first there is problem with showing the first `<section>`, sometimes you must resize window and than first `<section>` appear.

The second problem is with buttons in first `<section>`, look at search button please, why is it wider than normal?

Here is my page: http://www.nibaru.com/core/mainpage.html

Thanks.

Comment: Include all relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second problem:

Line 313 of theme-blues.css contains a declaration for .btn

This has "min-width: 155px;" set. Removing that fixes the button.